# Как задать фон через HTML?

Tags: html, css

Привет! Как можно сделать фон через img с фиксированным расположением, при любом разрешении?

```css
.b-background-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-background-image">
  <img src="/images/inhtml/catalog_bg.jpg" alt="" title="" class="b-background-image__image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вполне достаточно дать изображению фиксированное позиционирование и z-index меньший, чем у основного текста.
Куча test-div'ов приведена для наглядности. Вся суть в css

```css
.b-background-image { position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0;}

img.b-background-image__image {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-background-image">
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/img/sprites.png" alt="" title="" class="b-background-image__image"> 
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asd3f</div>
    <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf</div>
  <div class="test">asdf-end</div>
</div>
```